# View tree structure in a project in VSCode and W11

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-code

Even though I can print a tree structure in VSCode (Windows 11), the main problem I'm having is that I need to limit its depth, as I have so many folders and files, and I just need up to depth 2 or 3. I've tried:

- [Tree](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CTC.vscode-tree-extension): This would be the best as I can comprise the folders. However, when I run it, it shows an empty file.
- [File-tree-generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shinotatwu-DS.file-tree-generator): This one works but prints every single depth, without the possibility of limiting the depth.
- `tree /f /a /l2`
- `tree /f /a -depth 2`
- `show-tree -Depth 2` (from `Install-Script -Name Show-Tree`)

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/santisq/PSTree/ can do what you're looking for

Comment: `Tree` extension is not very helpful because it is **syntax highlighting** for a `tree` command output, if you look at the source code it does not implement any command. It only has a grammar file.

Comment: for standard Linux `tree` the option is `-L 2`

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue for so long i tried many types of module for tree but didn't work as i wanted but here i made a python module for current tree directory

run this :

```
pip install custom-tree
```

read the read documentation on https://github.com/dragon-devs/custom-tree. i'm gonna update to more advance.

give it a star if it helps you.

Comment: Could you please clarify your statement? I've been learning from Stack Overflow for quite some time, but this is my first time commenting. Just trying to understand your point better!

Comment: ohh that's alright ;)